# Examples of symplectromorphism other than $Sp(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

A linear symplectic form $ \omega$ on a vector space $V$ induces a symplectic structure (also denoted $ \omega$) on $V$ via the canonical identification of $TV$ with $V \times V$. 
The symplectic group $Sp(V )$ then embeds naturally in 
$Aut(V,\omega)$ (symplectromorphism), and the Lie algebra $sp(V)$ identifies with the subalgebra of 
$\chi(V, \omega)$ (Locally Hamiltonian Vector Field) consisting of vector fields of the form
$$X(v) = Av$$
for some $A \in sp(V)$.

I think $Aut(V,\omega)$ has elements other than $Sp(V)$.
For an operator in $Sp(V)$, it acts on the manifold $V$ in a homogeneous way. But I don't know how to find such an example, perphas in 2-dimensional case.

Another question is about the vector field $X(v)$, which is claimed to be the Hamiltonian vector field corresponding to
$$Q_A(v) = \frac{1}{2} \omega(Av, v) $$
I try to show that for vector field $Y(v)$
$$
\omega(X,Y(v))=dQ_A(Y(v))
$$
The RHS equals to 
$$
dQ_A(Y(v))=\frac{1}{2}\omega(AY(v), v)+\frac{1}{2}\omega(Av, Y(v)).
$$
But for $A\in sp(V)$, I don't know how to characterize this property.
Thus, I am stuck. Any advice on this problem will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any function $f$ with compact support and the Hamiltonian vector field defined by $\omega(X_f,.)=df$. The flow $\phi_t$ of $X_f$ is a flow of symplectomorphisms. If $f$ is not constant, then there exists $R$ such that for $\|x\|\geq R$, $\phi_t(x)=x$, but there exists $r>0$ such that the restriction of $\phi_t$ to the ball $B(0,r)$ is not the identity.

Comment: I see. So $Sp(V,\omega)$ corresponds to the specific type of $Q_A$. Thank you very much. 
And I have figured out my second question.

Answer (score 0):

For $A\in sp(V)$, we can consider $\exp(tA)\in Sp(V)$. Thus, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\omega(\exp(tA)Y,\exp(tA)v)=0.
$$
From this we obtain
$$
\omega(AY,v)+\omega(Y,Av)=0
$$